# Ajax Request problem, returns undefined 2 out of 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This might be a silly question, but I'm working on a homework project. Most of it is already working, but when I try to write some html with jquery inside an ajax request, two out of three return undefined.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "myurl",
            type: "Get",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + userpass));
            },
            dataType: "json",
        }).
            done(function (data) {
                $('#uebersicht').children(".item").remove();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#uebersicht').append("<p class='item' onclick='deleteitem(" + data[i].id + ")'>" +
                        data[i].datum + ", " + data[i].Stunden + " Stunden - " + data[i].Anmerkungen + "</p>");
                }
            });
```

I tried searching around, but I wasn't very lucky. Probably my searching is just off, but if someone could point me in the right direction I would be very glad.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to Parse the string data to json after it is received.

```
.done(function (data) {
   var data = JSON.parse(data); // Parse it here

   $('#uebersicht').children(".item").remove();
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         $('#uebersicht').append("<p class='item' onclick='deleteitem(" + data[i].id + ")'>" +
                            data[i].datum + ", " + data[i].Stunden + " Stunden - " + data[i].Anmerkungen + "</p>");
       }
    });
});


// Or you could use the `$.each()` function to loop through the data:

.done(function (data) {
    $('#uebersicht').children(".item").remove();
    $.each(data, function(item, element){
       $('#uebersicht').append("<p class='item' onclick='deleteitem(" + element.id + ")'>" +
                            element.datum + ", " + element.Stunden + " Stunden - " + element.Anmerkungen + "</p>");

    })     
});
```